# how to place Interstitial Ad After If Statement?

Tags: android, interstitial

I was Implemented interstitial Code to my App but I want interstitial Code in if-else statement ..so what to do ?

Comment: post your code what you have done .

Comment: if (url.endsWith(".mp3")) {
I want to place Implemented Code Here..

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
if (url.endsWith(".mp3")){
  // your ad view should be visible here. and load ad here.
}else{
 // your ad view should be gone here.
}
```